# Why should router be assigned a default gateway IP address?

Tags: networking, router, gateway, wan

I have a topology, as shown below-

[image]

Wherein 4 hosts are connected to the wireless router's LAN.
And the WAN port has been connected to another subnet.

Now when i need to configure the WAN port for the router, i see the portal like below-

[image]

**What does Default Gateway stands for here?**

*If it was a host, i understand the default gateway would be the nearest router to the host. What does it imply in the case of router itself?*

Comment: "A default gateway is the node in a computer network using the Internet Protocol Suite that serves as the forwarding host (router) to other networks when no other route specification matches the destination IP address of a packet." - [Default Gateway Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway)

Comment: So no difference. That is where the router will send all network traffic outside his known networks.

Comment: So, that means, I should be configuring the 'Default Gateway' on the router's WAN interface as 192.168.2.1 (which is the LAN interface's IP); since there is only 2 subnets connected with the router and there is no connected to the internet, right?

Comment: If you don't have/need other networks, you can leave it empty if you use it only to connect the 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24 networks.